# Audio without video is OK, but WITH video it is delayed

Tags: ffmpeg, sync

I have this audio filterchain (for repetitive short part of the original audio):

```
[1:a] atrim=start=2.52:end=1:38.0, aloop=100:7700 [audio]
```

When I used it *without* video, i. e. in the `ffmpeg` command I mapped only audio:

```
-map "[audio]"
```

then it fulfilled my intent - it started playing immediately (from `0:00`)

But when I mapped video, too

```
-map 0:v -map "[audio]"
```

then the audio started at `2.52` - the same value as in my `atrim` filter.

(I tried *changing* this value and the starting time *changed appropriately*, too.)

What is the reason for it and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to reset the timestamps:

```
[1:a]atrim=start=2.52:end=1:38.0,aloop=100:7700,asetpts=N/SR/TB[audio]
```